# Is there a generic way of building and maintaining a nested menu in React (Next.js)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The past couple of days, I've been working on a project with a navigation bar, implemented with TypeScript and React (Next.js). Until now, I've been using a single level navigation, but I'm moving towards a multi-level navigation menu, and I could use some help with it.

## Initial code: Single Level Menu

The initial code I have written was for a Single Level Menu, i.e. a simple navigation bar without submenus, containing links on the top level only. The code is as follows:

**1) Model / Type Definition**

```js
// @/models/NavLinks.d.ts

export interface NavItem {
  title: string;
  link: string;
  ariaLabel?: string;
}

export interface NavItemCollection {
  title?: string; // Titles are used in Sidebar, not in main Navbar in this example
  items: Array<NavItem>;
}

export type NavItemCollections = NavItemCollection[];
```

**2) Data:**

```js
// @/data/MainNav.ts

import { NavItemCollections } from "@/models/NavLinks";

export const NavLinks: NavItemCollections = [
  {
    items: [
      { title: "About", link: "/about" },
      { title: "Security", link: "/security" },
      { title: "Blog", link: "/blog" },
    ],
  },
];
```

**3) Usage:**

```js
// @/components/site/Navbar.tsx;

import Link from "next/link";
import { NavItemCollections } from "@/models/NavLinks";
import styles from "@/styles/Navbar.module.scss";

export interface NavbarProps {
  links: NavItemCollections;
}

export const Navbar = (props: NavbarProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
       {props.links.map((collection) =>
          collection.items.map((item, index) => (
            <Link href={item.link} key={index}>
              <a className={styles.link}>{item.title}</a>
            </Link>
          ))
        )}
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

... and then passing the links using the prop as specified. I.e. `<Navbar links={links} />` in a parent component.

P.S. Keep in mind that Next.js requires me to wrap `<a>` inside `<Link>`.

## My Goal: Multi Level Menu

My personal goal is to refactor the entire menu, so that I (and others) have one uniform way of implementing a well-structured, well-typed navigation menu that could be used in multiple places.

In order to do so, I borrowed some code from VuePress 2, which uses something similar in their default theme.

**1) Model / Type Definition**

```js
// @/models/NavLinks.d.ts

/**
 * Base nav item, displayed as text
 */
export interface NavItem {
  text: string;
  ariaLabel?: string;
}

/**
 * Base nav group, has nav items children
 */
export interface NavGroup<T> extends NavItem {
  children: T[];
}

/**
 * NavLink, i.e. inherited from NavItem, but extended with link properties.
 */
export interface NavLink extends NavItem {
  link: string;
  rel?: string;
  target?: string;
}

/**
 * Navbar Contents
 */
export type NavbarItem = NavLink;
export type NavbarGroup = NavGroup<NavbarGroup | NavbarItem | string>;
export type NavbarContents = (NavbarItem | NavbarGroup | string)[];
```

**2) Data**

With our new model, we could work a multi-level menu, i.e. items with children, with items and optionally children, etc. In other words: a nested navigation structure. Cool.

```js
// @/data/MainNav.ts

import { NavbarContents } from "@/models/NavLinks";

export const NavLinks: NavbarContents = [
  { text: "About", link: "/about" },
  { text: "Security", link: "/security" },
  { text: "Blog", link: "/blog" },
  {
    text: "Professional",
    children: [
      { text: "Individual", link: "/professional" },
      { text: "Business", link: "/business" },
    ],
  },
];
```

**3) Usage:**

This is where I got stuck. If I am using the same `.map()` approach as shown earlier, I get the following error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | NavLink | NavbarGroup'.
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

The error is quite obvious, as you cannot use `.map` on a `string` type, but what should I use instead? I tried to use `typeof` in order to decide if it's a string. Then just render the string...

```
<nav className={styles.navlinks}>
         {props.links.map((collection) =>
           typeof (collection) === "string" ?
             <span className="string">{collection}</span>
             : (...)
```

And I'm left with either a `NavLink` or `NavbarGroup`. No clue how to implement them.

The question is: How can I have a nested menu using the type definition and data from above?

Comment: "If I am using the same .map() approach" - what exactly is the code? If `children` is an array, you need to iterate over it. The question shouldn't really be asked for Vue because things can be different there, and you don't know beforehand how. In case you need Vue SSR, there's more than 1 framework for that

Comment: Absolutely right. I was thinking of Vue 3's SFCs with <v-for> syntaxis. Anyway, I should focus on React (Next.js) now.

When mapping the collection, the type you're working with is either `string | NavLink | NavbarGroup`. I could use `typeof` for the 1st iteration, but as an iteratable `NavGroup` could also contain a `string`, I'm facing the same problem, just a level deeper. Recursion...

P.S. I will update the title.

Comment: Are there unlimited levels of nesting? You need recursive function or more likely,  component. It should accept an array of items, which would be `NavLinks` itself at level 0, and `children` array for deeper levels. You'll need to extract this to a component to make recursion work with v-for in Vue any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the type information where it asks. And you can use a recursive method to render the menu like below.

```
import { NavLinks } from "./MainNav";
import { NavbarContents, NavbarItem, NavbarGroup } from "./NavLinks";

export default function App() {
  const renderMenu = (links: NavbarContents) => {
    return links.map((menuItem: NavbarItem | NavbarGroup | string) => (
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>
        <a href={menuItem?.link}>{menuItem?.text}</a>
        {menuItem?.children && renderMenu(menuItem?.children)}
      </div>
    ));
  };

  return <div>{renderMenu(NavLinks)}</div>;
}
```

You can extend this code as per your menu item types. When you do that it will be set of switch cases instead of `<a href={menuItem?.link}>{menuItem?.text}</a>` which works for `NavbarItem`.

code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-smoke-zzxt4?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you @Amila Senadheera :)

Made some small changes in order to get it into a `<nav><ul><li></li></ul></nav>` structure, but the idea remains the same https://codesandbox.io/s/zdjyr.

This is awesome! Thank you very much. I'm going to try putting this in my Next.js app.